# Change one sheet's name when another is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a dashboard/stats for employees at my company, and I've run into a bit of a hiccup with one of my codes. Here's a bit of background to start

Each employee has 2 sheets with their different stats.

The first sheet is always visible and has a macro that will un-hide and activate the 2nd sheet (so that the workbook doesn't get too unmanageable.) When you click off the 2nd sheet, I have a macro that will hide it (it uses `workbook_Sheetdeactivate` to close the sheet if it has properties related to the 2nd sheet)

The first sheet's tab-name is added to a cell (in my case `range("A62"))`, with the formula `"=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)"`.

I then make that cell equal to `range("A1")` on the second sheet. What I want is for the the name of the 2nd sheet to equal `range("A1")` & " Achievements", so that the 2nd sheet can be referenced in my macros by the first sheet. (Ex: if sheet1 is "Bobby", sheet2 is "Bobby Achievements")

I didn't have trouble writing the macro itself, but I don't know which sub would be best to use so that the macro is activated at the right time. Is there a way to have the macro run whenever a sheetname is changed in the workbook?

Here's the code:

```
dim ws as worksheet

'Sorting through each sheet to find "Achievement Sheets"
For Each ws in Workbook
    If ws.range("W1").Value = "Achievement Lists" Then
        ws.name = ws.Range("A1") & " Achievements"
    End if
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a bit crude, but you could simply use the 'Calculate' event on the second worksheet object to update its own name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A1") & " Achievements" <> Me.Name Then
        Me.Name = Range("A1") & " Achievements"
    End If
End Sub
```

or use the 'SheetCalculate event in the workbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sh.Range("W1").Value = "Achievement Lists" Then
        If Sh.Range("A1").Value & " Achievements" <> Sh.Name Then
            Sh.Name = Sh.Range("A1") & " Achievements"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing something like that (I'm not one to avoid being a little crude, haha). The problem is, I want this code to work for any employee that I'm adding through a different macro, If it could be one code to work for the whole workbook instead of one I would have to add to each sheet it'd be a lot better for me

Comment: Okay Just did a bunch more research, looks like this is the only way that I can find to do it. I'll make it work, thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a 'SheetCalculate' event in the Workbook object you could use instead. Updated answer to elaborate.